# submit form with cloned fields

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form to submit products with a button that clones fields if more fields are needed:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="index.php">
<div class="card card-primary">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h3 class="card-title">Products</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="modeliai">
      <div class="modelioforma">
        <div class="formroup">
          <label for="model">Model</label>
          <input type="model" class="form-control" placeholder="Model name..." name="model" id="model">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>SKU</label>
              <input type="sku" class="form-control" placeholder="SKU..." name="sku" id="sku">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="supplier">supplier</label>
              <select class="custom-select rounded-0" id="supplier" name="supplier">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Quantity</label>
              <input type="qty" class="form-control" value="1" name="qty" id="qty">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Price</label>
              <input type="price" class="form-control" placeholder="price..." name="price" id="price">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="addMore"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add more</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" form="myForm" value="Submit">Submit form</button>
</div>
```

javascript for cloning fields when clicking Add more button:

```
<script>
$("#addMore").click(function(){   
    $(".modelioforma:last").clone().appendTo(".modeliai");  
});
</script>
```

And then php code just to catch submitted form fields:

```
if (!empty($_POST))
{
  $modelis = $_POST['model'];
  $sku = $_POST['sku'];
  $supplier = $_POST['supplier'];
  $qty= $_POST['qty'];
  $price = $_POST['price'];
    echo $model.'<br>';
  echo $sku.'<br>';
  echo $supplier.'<br>';
  echo $qty.'<br>';
  echo $price.'<br>';
}
```

If I submit only one product with its fields filled without clone button pressed, then everything works fine, but If I use Add more button to clone fields and submit more than one product after $_POST is processed Im get only last product added. How do I get all products submitted after clone button is pressed, so I can work with items further.. adding them to database ect.

Comment: the last element is replacing the information on $_POST, you need to give diferent ````name=""```` when you do the clone

Comment: Or make them into arrays always even for only one EG `name="supplier[]"` and `name="sku"` etc etc

Comment: Making the cloned fields an array is certainly the best way to go on this. add [] to the end of each form elements name, then in PHP the post value will be an array of values that you can loop over

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments I've added `name="supplier[]"` ect. in my form and then just got it via $_POST into array `$supplier[] = $_POST['supplier'];`
Thank you very much everyone.